# What is the name of the "polka style" music preceding the Waltz in Final Fantasy VIII?

Tags: final-fantasy, theme-music

Every fan of Final Fantasy VIII should  know the famous ballroom scene.
For a reminder, here is the opening video:

Now the music starting at 3:05 is quite famous among the fans, this is Waltz for the Moon from [Nobuo Uematsu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nobuo_Uematsu). But what I am searching for is the name of the preceding music, from the start of the video to 2:27 which is a kind of polka. I tried to shazam it but no result.

Anybody know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, it's listed as "[Dance with the Balamb Fish](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Balamb_Town)" in the official Soundtrack. It was also composed by Nobuo Uematsu.